# Test my Ubuntu DNS

Tags: ubuntu, dns, resolve

I have been installed and setup my own DNS on Ubuntu 16.04.

I did this:

```
 /etc/bind/named.conf.options
```

Change file contents to:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { 63.142.252.119; 127.0.0.1; };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
};

logging {
        channel default {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" versions 3 size 16m;
        };
        category default { default; };
};
```

Also:
`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

Make it look like:

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.db";
        };
```

Next, open (create) zone file:

`/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.db`

And put domain data there:

```
$TTL 600
mydomain.com.      IN      SOA     ns1.mydomain.com. admin.mydomain.com. (
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
)

mydomain.com.      IN      NS              ns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.      IN      NS              ns2.mydomain.com.

mydomain.com.      IN      MX     10       mta.mydomain.com.

mydomain.com.       IN      A       63.142.252.119
*                   IN      A       63.142.252.119

ns1.mydomain.com.              IN      A       63.142.252.119
ns2.mydomain.com.              IN      A       63.142.252.119

www              IN      A       63.142.252.119
mta              IN      A       63.142.252.119
```

I did restart bind9 and now trying to ping my ns1.mydoman.com and I am getting `'ping: unknown host ns1.mydomain.com'`

Shouldn't I had some regular response for the result if everything is okay?
{mydomain.com is not yet configured on my domain provider}

Answer (score 0):

At the end, everything was okay, just my country domain registrar needs some time to do domain propagation.